# How to query points north of a certain latitude

Tags: postgis, geodjango

I have a Django model with a geodjango PointField:

```
geopoint = gis_models.PointField(srid=4326, verbose_name='location', geography=True, null=True)
```

I want to query the model for all points North of a certain latitude.

It ought to be easy, just a > on the latitude component of the point, but I can't find any example of how to do that among the endless examples of distance queries, bounding boxes etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to helpful people of #postgis IRC I have found a way to do this...

**Firstly: the way to query against the latitude of a point in PostGIS is via the `ST_y` function.**

As far as I can tell none of the [GeoDjango queryset lookups](https://django.readthedocs.io/en/1.4.X/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets.html) map directly to that function though :(

There is a `strictly_above` lookup (AFAICT 'above' means 'north of') but it doesn't work for me because my field has `geography=True` and:

```
ValueError: PostGIS geography does not support the "strictly_above" lookup.
```

Thanks to help on #postgis IRC I learned I can cast my geographic field to geometry and thus use `ST_y`. As a raw PostGIS SQL query it looks like:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM place WHERE st_y(geopoint::geometry) > 51.508129
```

### The answer:

In Django ORM it looks like:

```py
Place.objects.extra(where=["st_y(geopoint::geometry) > %s"], params=['51.508129']).count()
```

#### Further thoughts:

It's a shame we can't use the existing `strictly_above` ORM lookup, because of two limitations:

1. No way in the ORM to cast geography to geometry (though there is [an 'accepted' ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17635) for adding this to geodjango)
2. If we use `extra(select={...` to add a cast-to-geometry version of the point field to the queryset we [can't filter on it (and "won't fix" in Django)](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13363), except by adding another `extra(where=...` clause, in which case we're no better off than above

Out of curiosity I wanted to try the `strictly_above` query anyway. In PostGIS this is the `|>>` operator and the raw SQL, comparing my point field to another arbitrary point, looks like:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM place WHERE geopoint::geometry |>> ST_GeomFromText('Point(-0.128005 51.508129)', 4326);
```

It returns the same answer as the other query so I'm pretty sure the meaning is the same.

Comment: Also possibly useful info, eg if trying to find "points 100 miles North of" another point: http://geography.about.com/library/faq/blqzdistancedegree.htm ... 1 degree of latitude = approx 69 miles / 111 km

Comment: please note the date on my answer... some of the limitations in Django/GeoDjango may have been fix since

Comment: since Django 1.10 it should be possible to: `Place.objects.annotate(geom_point=Cast('geopoint', PointField())).filter(geom_point__strictly_above='POINT(-95.3385 29.7245)').count()`